# "Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=501" while registering ios devicetoken in gcm

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

GLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error -25300.).

Please get me out of this.

Comment: can you confirm you have generated the relevant certificates (.p12) and set them up via: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add ?

Comment: Yes i uploaded APNS p12 certificates and got the gcm plist files. It was worked fine 1 week back, suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950731/ios-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-not-receiving-remote-notifications

Answer (score 0):

The error log message `GLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300` is traced often, both when receiving google token succeeds or fails. I assume this is not an actual error.

I started receiving the error `Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=501` on one device. No matter how many times I retried the call to `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler:`  it always returned 501. I tried deleting the app, I tried restarting the device with no luck. I noticed that the same code ran fine on other devices. As a final resort I reset all data and settings on the device (factory reset) and this fixed the problem for me.